# How to query from eloquent?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, many-to-many

ERD :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryAQx.png)

**Model**

1. `Student` : id
2. `Course`  : id
3. `Student_Course` (payment) : id, student_id, course_id

The relation between `Student` and `Course` is Many to Many, because of that I make another table `Student_Course`.

I have one question, that is **Show total amount of students that enroll at least 1 course**.

Please help me to find the result. I stuck on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try following example:

```
Model/Student.php //write relationship in your model

public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'payment');
}
```

and then try with following eloquent query

```
$students = Student::whereHas('courses')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: What is HorseTraining ? That is model ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Student extends Model {

    public function student_courses() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StudentCourses');
    }
}


$students = Student::whereHas('student_courses')->get();
```